# regex pattern to match the end of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Can someone tell me the regex pattern to match everything to the right of the last "/" in a string.

For example, str="red/white/blue";

I'd like to match "blue" because it is *everything* to the right of the last "/".

Many thanks!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use the [`$` metacharacter](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/perlre.html#Metacharacters) to match the end of a string.

In Perl, this looks like:

```
my $str = 'red/white/blue';
my($last_match) = $str =~ m/.*\/(.*)$/;
```

Written in JavaScript, this looks like:

```
var str = 'red/white/blue'.match(/.*\/(.*)$/);
```

Comment: I am using javascript and this works fine. Thanks very much. One question though: I also tested without the "?" with this pattern /.*\/(.*)$/ and it also seems to work. Can you please tell me the difference. Thanks again.

Comment: That article is pretty terrible. It doesn't even have examples, analysis, or sample uses.

Comment: Greedy quantifiers will perform better here since they grab all characters the quantified patterns can match at once, thus getting to the end of string (`$`) quicker. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 32):

Use this Regex pattern: `/([^/]*)$`

Answer (score 8):

Should be

```
~/([^/]*)$~
```

Means: Match a `/` and then everything, that is not a `/` (`[^/]*`) until the end (`$`, "end"-anchor).

I use the `~` as delimiter, because now I don't need to escape the forward-slash `/`.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work:  `/([^/]*)$`

What language are you using?  End-of-string regex signifiers can vary in different languages.

Answer (score 4):

Use following pattern:

```
/([^/]+)$
```