# What's the right regular expression to match the exact word at the end of a string and excluding all other urls with more chars at the end?

Tags: regex

I have to match an exact string at the end of a url, but not match all other urls that have more characters after that string

I can better explain with example.

I need to match the url having the string 'white' at its end: http//mysite.com/white

But I also need to not match urls having one or more characters postponed to it, like http//mysite.com/white__blue or http//mysite.com/white/yellow or http//mysite.com/white/

How to do that?

Thanks

Comment: `white$` would ensure `white` is at the end of string.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494915/regex-pattern-to-match-the-end-of-a-string

Answer (score 1):

Regex to match any url*

```
^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+\.[a-z\.]{2,6}|[\d\.]+)([\/:?=&#]{1}[\da-z\.-]+)*[\/\?]?$
```

Regex to match a url containing white in the end

```
^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+\.[a-z\.]{2,6}|[\d\.]+)([\/:?=&#]{1}[\da-z\.-]+)*[\/\?]?white$
```

You can check the regex [here](http://regexr.com/3g2oe)

- From regexr.com 
  It does not match urls(which are not valid anyway) like

  - `httpabrakadabra.co//`
  - `http:google.com`
  - `http://no-tld-here-folks.a`
  - `http://potato.54.211.192.240/`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your limited sample inputs, I'd say you could get away with this very minimal pattern:

`^http[^\s]+white$`

However, depending on what you are truly trying to achieve, what language/function you are implementing this pattern with, and what the full input string looks like, this pattern may need to be refined.

It would be best if you would improve your question to include all of the above relevant information.