# With PHP/Preg, how is it possible to replace a string not followed by any character

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

For example, I have two strings

1. "abcdef"
2. "abcdefghijk"

I want to replace the first one, but not the second one which begins with the same string. However, the first one can be followed by any ponctuation such like `,` `;` `?` `.` and so on. So, I have to replace `abcdef` only, if there is no other character A-Z, a-z, after the string.

I probably have to use `preg_replace`, but I don't see how to write my regex string to exclude the strings followed by any character.

I tried of course to replace the string without to take care of the characters following this string, and it is running of course. `str_replace` is enough for that, but it is not enough in my case.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494915/regex-pattern-to-match-the-end-of-a-string can help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you provide more example data? both of subject and pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that makes sure we haven't letter after the match.

```
\babcdef(?![a-zA-Z])
```

[Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/OJUrCm/2)